# How to import key BLOB generated from Microsoft CryptExportKey from Linux

Tags: rsa

I have a private/public key pair saved as key BLOBs which were in fact exported with the Microsoft "CryptExportKey" API. Now I need to use the same key pair (specially the public key) under Linux environment. Is there anyway to import the public key from my "public key BLOB" in Linux?

My requirement is, I create a document and then sign it with my private key. This part is done under Windows environment with Microsoft Cryptography API. Now I have to use this document from Linux. To do that I need to use the public key.